# python : working with german umlaut

Tags: python, unicode, diacritics

```
months = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]

print months[2].decode("utf-8")
```

Printing month[2] fails with

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid data
```

help to get rid of this!

Comment: works perfectly in my python2 interpreter. Most likely a coding fail of the file, did you add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Did you add an encoding in the begining of your source file ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you are working in UTF8?

Nevertheless, I would recommend to define

```
months = [u"Januar", u"Februar", u"März", u"April", u"Mai", u"Juni",
          u"Juli", u"August", u"September", u"Oktober", u"November", u"Dezember"]

print months[2]
```

and if you do some stuff basing on bytes, you `encode()` the data into the charset you need.