# Django does not save a field containing umlauts

Tags: python, database, django, encoding, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python : working with german umlaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254047/python-working-with-german-umlaut)

I try to populate a database field using some exif metadata from images in `django-admin`. I decode it correctly meaning `print` does show the string with umlauts. However when I call `save()` on the model the string never apears in the database(sqlite). It works just fine with strings without umlauts as well as with constant strings containing umlauts. There are no errors or something that would give me a hint on what went wrong. Which is why I do not know what to search for.

I'm trying to isolate the important parts of code:

The models `save` function:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.url = slugify(self.name) 
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `save_model` function in the `admin.py` file:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if("original_image" in request.FILES):
        file = request.FILES["original_image"]
        if (not obj.description):
          from silbertools.get_exif import get_exif
          obj.description = get_exif(file)
        if (not obj.name):
          obj.name = unicode(file)[:-4][:100]
    obj.save()
```

The relevant `description` field is defined as follows:

```
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The `get_exif` function:

```
def get_exif(fn):
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    if info:
        for tag, value in info.items():
            decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
            if (decoded == "UserComment"):
                var = value[8:].decode('latin1')
                print(u"The string is: {0}".format(var))
                return var
    return u""
```

The `get_exif()` function does work well as far as I can tell by the print statement. I verified that the description is set correctly in `save_model()` right before the `obj.save()`.

Still nothing seems to help as soon as there is an umlaut in the string and the string is read from the exif metadata it does not show up in the database. There is no error the rest of the model is added as expected just the description field is blank.

I hope somebody can extract enough information to help me get to to the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No that is not my problem! I do not get any error! And everything prints just fine. It's just not stored to the database.

Answer (score -1):

works fine in the interpreter, did you add an encoding at the top of your module?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

test = "März"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test.decode('utf-8')
```

edit: a brief search for *python+umlaut*, this answer was already given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254047/python-working-with-german-umlaut)

Comment: Yes I did add the encoding. As said I don't get any error. And even without the encoding everything should be alright because all the sources of strings are external. The encoding is only used for the string constants that are defined in this particular file afaik.